# $\int\limits_0^4\int\limits_\sqrt x^2 \dfrac x{1+y^5}\ dy\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to find

$$
\int_0^4\int_\sqrt x^2 \dfrac x{1+y^5}\ dy\ dx=\ ...?
$$

The correct answer from my textbook is $\frac1{10}\log33$. I can answer it if the integrand is  $\dfrac x{1+y^2}$ so I can let $y=\tan t$ but not for $\dfrac x{1+y^5}$.

This is my homework with 10 questions but I can only answer 8 questions, two of them I'm stuck. Can anyone help me for this one? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The region of integration, $0 \le x \le 4$ and $\sqrt x \le y \le 2$, can also be defined as $0 \le y \le 2$ and $0 \le x \le y^2$. If you change the order of integration, using this new definition as your limits, you will find that everything falls out nicely.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: i get it now, thank you