# Double integration. Do I have to integrate $(1+x^{3})^{1/2}$? (which I thought was impossible)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

[image]

Or is there a theorem(or method) that will allow me to avoid that?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/798677/1508) is a similar problem, if you want some practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Change the order of integration as

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x^2}\sqrt{1+x^3} dy dx. $$

Comment: I see how you got the $x^{2}$, but not why the 1 changed to a 0. Can you explain please?

Comment: Nevermind, nevermind. I logic'd my way through it. Thank you!

Comment: @Bob: Plot the region to see what's going on. You have to consider taking a vertical strip instead of the horizontal one.